# How to play music with Discord.py Rewrite (1.0.0) version

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py rewrite to make a discord bot. I know that this is all written in the documentation, but documentation is really confusing. I want a bot to connect to my channel and then play music from youtube link.

I currently have this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if(message.content == "play playlist"):
        # some code to play link that I have in local file
```

Again, documentation is very confusing and unclear for me.

If you need more info please comment.

Thanks!

Comment: See the [`basic_voice.py` bot from the examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/basic_voice.py)

Comment: Thank you but that looks like discord.py 0.16(old version) I am using rewrite (1.0.0) which is different

Comment: That is the rewrite version. Note it uses `ctx.send` over `client.send_message`